# How to concatenate more than two SMAS?

Tags: pine-script

I'm struggling with pine script on TV, I know how to concatenate two SMAS but I don't know how to do it when it comes to more than two. 1) Is that even possible? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What does that mean to concatenate SMAs?
Concatenate is a word we use for strings to merge them into 1 string
Example:

```
var string a = "best"
var string b = "trading"
c = a + " " + b // best trading
```

Comment: thank you! Let me clarify it, what I'm looking for is how to put the result of a sma as the period of other sma. sma (sma). Thank you

Comment: then do ta.sma(ta.sma(close, 15), 15) for example